# Cell is not inserting from CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

Im working on this tableview that gets the info from a CoreData object, the thing is that when I try to add an object to the CoreData and the tableview does not work, I want this to be animated, this is what Im trying:

In the CoreDataBase(core data methods):

```
+(void)insertNewTask:(NSString *) task
            withnote:(NSString *) note
         withnotDate:(NSDate *) notdate{

    [MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

        Task *thetask = [Task MR_createEntity];
        thetask.task = task;
        thetask.note = note;
        thetask.date = [NSDate date];
        thetask.notdate = notdate;

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Accounts:%d", [CoreDataBase numberofTasks]);
    }];

}
```

And in the tableview controller, the update happens when returning from a textfield, that text is the one that is supose to be added into the tableview and into the coredata(only adds into coredata because when I reopen I can see all objects in the table):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1];

    [CoreDataBase insertNewTask:textField.text withnote:textField.text withnotDate:date];

    [self reloadCards];

    textField.text = @"";
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(0) inSection:0];

    [self.tableview beginUpdates];


    [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[self keyForIndexPath:newIndexPath]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

    [self.tableview endUpdates];



    [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    [CoreDataBase logAllTasks];

    return YES;
}

-(void)reloadCards{

    self.allTasks = [[CoreDataBase allTasksWithDateSort:NO] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

And this is how I display the info into the table(as I said only loads in Reopen, not in the returning of the textfield):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;
        [tableView setRowHeight:73];
        Task *task = self.allTasks[indexPath.row];
        cell.taskTitle.text = [task task];
}
```

So I hope I explained well my problem, Im working with MagicalRecord so the methods for counting of rows and all that are not to complicated, thats why I dont post them, thanks and hope you help me

Comment: Your best bet is to use `NSFetchedResultsController`. There is some discussion here https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/404

Comment: Hi, if it is not too much to ask, can you explain me in an answer how can I apply it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `NSFetchedResultsController` instance on your viewcontroller. Then make the viewcontroller to be a delegate for `NSFetchedResultsController` object. To do that you should support `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol on your viewcontroller. Read more here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html